# Float number always round up

Tags: php, rounding

I have a float number. I want to round it like this:

```
1.301  => 1.31
1.309  => 1.31
1.3001 => 1.30
1.3009 => 1.30
```

So far, I have tried this:

```
$number = ceil($number * 100) / 100;
```

This is almost perfect, but still not perfect:

```
1.3301 => 1.34 // It should be 1.33
```

Is there a way to solve my problem?

**Resolved**
Answer from Niet the Dark Absol:

```
$number = ceil( floor($number*1000) / 10) / 100;
```

Comment: http://php.net/round and pay attention to 3rd parameter. Choose the one that fits your need.

Comment: -blinks- Um... Why are you saying that `1.3301` should round "up" to `1.33`?

Comment: That's not rounding up.  1.3009 => 1.30 is rounding DOWN.

Comment: Why don't you just cut the precision to 3 digits and then use your code?

Comment: `ceil()` always rounds up (it's short for ceiling) - `floor()` always rounds down ... you probably want `round()` which will round to the nearest integer (or float to a given precision) : http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Read the OP's examples carefully everyone. For some reason they want to round x.y000 to x.y009 **down**, then round everything else **up**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you appear to be doing is rounding down to three digits, then rounding up to two.

I'm not going to pretend to know how this makes sense.

```
$number = ceil( floor($number*1000) / 10) / 100;
```

To keep two decimal places, add:

```
$number = number_format($number,2);
// OR:
$number = sprintf("%.2f",$number);
```

But note that both the above result in a *string*, so should only be used for output.

Comment: Yeah - I have to admit, on closer inspection of the question ... I'm now more confused that I was when I only gave it a cursory glance O_o

Comment: This doesn't produce what the OP wants. OP wants it as `1.30`, but this one will produce `1.3` instead.

Comment: +1 but you'll probably find that you may as well have written `$number = rand()` given that the spec is so ropey.

Comment: @AmalMurali you know the difference between a floating point number a a string right?

Comment: @CD001: Yes. How's that actually relevant? I'm talking about (formatting) the **output**, not input.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Given the question actually say anything about it, I've changed my DV to UV.

Comment: @AmalMurali - he's using floats not strings (according to the question) therefore 1.3 === 1.30 - output isn't relevant really as I understood the question.